# CarouFredSel sliding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I have set up a caroufredsel, and have items inside of it. But when I click on my next and previous buttons, the first time it appears to shift 1 item, every click after that it shifts the entire width of the content and back to the beginning.

I have set my scroll items to 3. Does it have something to do with the width of the container?

```
jQuery('#tab-1').find('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                            responsive : true,
                            circular: false,
                            align: "center",
                            height : 'auto',
                            width : 'auto',
                            auto : false,
                            prev : {
                                button : function() {
                                    return jQuery('#tab-1').find('.carousel-pagerLeft');
                                }
                            },
                            next : {
                                button : function() {
                                    return jQuery('#tab-1').find('.carousel-pagerRight');
                                }
                            },
                            scroll : {
                                items : 3,
                                fx : "fade"
                            },  
                            items : {
                                height : 'auto',
                                width: 'auto'
                            },
                            swipe: {
                                onMouse: true,
                                onTouch: true
                            }               
                        });
```

It also seems that on slide, the height of the carousel changes for some reason. maybe this is related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the caroufredsel width to 100% did the trick.

```
jQuery('#tab-1').find('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                            responsive : true,
                            circular: false,
                            align: "center",
                            height : 'auto',
                            width : '100%',
                            auto : false,
                            prev : {
                                button : function() {
                                    return jQuery('#tab-1').find('.carousel-pagerLeft');
                                }
                            },
                            next : {
                                button : function() {
                                    return jQuery('#tab-1').find('.carousel-pagerRight');
                                }
                            },
                            scroll : {
                                items : 3,
                                fx : "fade"
                            },  
                            items : {
                                height : 'auto',
                                width: 'auto'
                            },
                            swipe: {
                                onMouse: true,
                                onTouch: true
                            }               
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also refactor your selector to be simpler as you are using IDs and there should only be one per page anyway:

Instead of:

```
jQuery('#tab-1').find('#carousel').carouFredSel();
```

Use this:

```
jQuery('#carousel').carouFredSel();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it was a lot more complex. It is a dynamic page and the number of tabs varies heavily. This was just the simple form for SO to review.